# How to filter a mysql database with user input on a website and then spit the filtered table back to the website?

Tags: mysql, database, web-applications, web-hosting

I've been researching this on google for literally 3 weeks, racking my brain and still not quite finding anything. I can't believe this is so elusive.
(I'm a complete beginner so if my terminology sounds stupid then that's why.)

I have a database in mysql/phpmyadmin on my web host.
I'm trying to create a front end that will allow a user to specify criteria for querying the database in a way that they don't have to know sql, basically just combo boxes and checkboxes on a form.
Then have this form 'submit' a query to the database, and show the filtered tables.

This is how the SQL looks in Microsoft Access:

```
PARAMETERS TEXTINPUT1 Text ( 255 ), NUMBERINPUT1 IEEEDouble;
// pops up a list of parameters for the user to input

SELECT DISTINCT Table1.Column1, Table1.Column2, Table1.Column3,*
// selects only the unique rows in these three columns

FROM Table1
// the table where this query is happening

WHERE (((Table1.Column1) Like TEXTINPUT1] AND ((Table1.Column2)<=[NUMBERINPUT1] AND ((Table1.Column3)>=[NUMBERINPUT1]));
// the criteria for the filter, it's comparing the user input parameters to the data in the rows and only selecting matches according to the equal sign, or greater than + equal sign, or less than + equal sign
```

What I don't get: WHAT IN THE WORLD AM I SUPPOSED TO USE (that isn't totally hard)!?

I've tried google fusion tables - doesn't filter right with numerical data or empty cells in rows, can't relate tables

I've tried DataTables.net, can't filter right with numerical data and can't use SQL without a bunch of indepth knowledge, not even sure it can if you have that..

I've looked into using jQuery with google spreadsheets, doesn't work at all either

I have no idea how I'm supposed to build a front end with my database. Every place that looks promising (like zohocreator) is asking for money, and is far too simplified to be able to do the LIKE criteria or SELECT DISTINCT stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have php & MySQL on server and will be using HTML and ajax as front end . A simplified scenario for your example is.

HTML has 3 inputs and sends an ajax request to a php file.

php has

```
// Get parameters from URL
$input1 = $_GET["input1"];
$input2 = $_GET["input2"];
$input3 = $_GET["input3"];
//connect to database

 $query = sprintf("SELECT *  FROM tablename WHERE column = %s  AND column2 <= %s AND column3 = >%s",$input1,$input2,input3);
```

This query is then executed.

A more complex query can be generated by building  it in blocks.

If this is what you are looking for I can elaborate on the whole technique

Comment: yeah php and mySQL on server and I'll use whatever I can as the front end. Definitely won't be writing the code manually though I'm brand new, looking for a semi-visual way to create this app. What I posted was an oversimplification in reality I'm dealing with hundreds of tables and hundreds of thousands of rows.

Comment: This scenario is a simplified version of what is available in phpMyAdmin. Obviously your application will be different. If you give me some of the basic details I can run up a demo

Comment: +1, Remember to escape your fields to avoid SQL injections if you use php ext/mysql or ext/mysqli connector.